# Java | Spliting Double to 2 integers| Getting error using substring & valueOf with str buffer

Tags: java, variables, split, double

this is my first question on this site.
What I am trying to do is to use 1 instance variable to create a matrix array.

long story short I tried to use a double and use each 'side' as a separate 'instance variable'.

It does works, ONCE...
After I try to use it again I get:

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
```

My questions are:

1. Why it fails to work more than once, why the error happening?
2. Is there a better way to do it? (while still using only 1 instance
   variable)

Here is some of my code:

```
/**
 * Get the fractional part of the double
 * @return the fractional part as an int
 */
private int getY() {
    String buffer = "";
    int i = 0;
    double xyCopy = _xy; 
    while (xyCopy > 0) { 
        xyCopy = (int) ((int) xyCopy / 10);
        i++;
    }
    buffer = String.valueOf(_xy);
    buffer = buffer.substring(i + 1);
    i = Integer.valueOf(buffer);
    return i;
}

private void setY(int yDimension) {
    int i=0;
    double yCopy = yDimension; 
    while (yCopy > 0) {
        yCopy = (int) ((int) yCopy / 10);
        i++;
    }
    _xy = _xy + (yDimension * Math.pow(10, -i));
}
```

Comment: what's the input number?

Comment: you'll get no luck storing decimal values in double. and what if xyCopy < 0?

Comment: the xyCopy is always positive. for input I used :
    testm.setY(100);

Answer (score 1):

why so complicated? you could just aswell use a string to get the fractional part as integer like this:

```
String s = String.valueOf(someDouble);
int after = s.indexOf('.');
int fractional = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(after + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it didn't work :\
I got :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "667889999997"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)

when I tried to use ur code.
I have still no idea why this is happening..

Comment: this format exception is caused, because the value is larger than the maximum that `int` can hold. you could try using `long` instead. Though most likely the biggest issue is simply the imprecision of `double`, which is causing these huge numbers in the fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first parsing string to double and then casting it to int or long . that way even if it doesn't fit for a int or long you'll get truncated value

```
    double d = 1.7777777777777777777772;
    String s = d+"";
    int pos = s.indexOf(".");
    long value = 0;
    if(pos>=0){
        String frac = s.substring(pos+1);
        value = (long)Double.parseDouble(frac);
    }
    System.out.println(value);
```